# Get largest Image from URL via php

Tags: php, image

Is it possible to find the largest Image from the one I get back.

Here is the Code I have so far:

```
    <?php
$url="https://wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       echo $tag ->getAttribute('src');

}
?>
```

For example img 1: 420x120px ; img 2: 1200x300px --> output link Url from img 2

Comment: Check [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php#refsect1-function.getimagesize-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getimagesize()` and `max()` in following way:-

```
$size_array = array(); // create an new empty array
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       $size_array[getimagesize($tag ->getAttribute('src'))] = $tag ->getAttribute('src'); 

       //assign size as key and path as value to the newly created array
}
$max_size = max(array_keys($size_array)); // get max size from keys array
$max_file = $size_array[$max_size]; // find out file path based on max-size
```

***Note:- I have assumed that `$tag ->getAttribute('src')` is giving you path of the image files***

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create an array containing summations of all `width`s and corresponding `height`s and desc sort it:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $array[] = [
        $tag->getAttribute('width') + $tag->getAttribute('height'),
        $tag->getAttribute('src')
    ];
}
array_multisort($array, SORT_DESC);
var_dump($array[0][1]);
```